# How to log all files inside a folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I want to navigate into a specific folder and then print all the files inside that specified folder using Google Apps Script:

```js
function listFilesinSpecFolder(){
    var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("specific folder id placed here");
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      Logger.log(file.getName());
    }
}
```

When I tried to log this it gives me an error saying that hasNext() function is not a function.
But when I run the below code it gives me no errors...

```js
function folder(){
    var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
    while (folders.hasNext()) {
      var folder = folders.next();
      Logger.log(folder.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script will help you '*to navigate into a specific folder and then print all the files inside that specified folder*'

**CODE**:

```
function listFilesinSpecFolder() {

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER ID GOES HERE');
  var file;
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();    
    Logger.log(file.getName());     
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("specific folder id placed here");`
this does not return files, it will **return a folder**

instead try something like:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("specific folder id placed here");

var files = folder.getFiles()
```

Comment: Croojimans Hi, thank you for your comment. But my goal is different from your answer... I am trying to log all my files inside a specific folder, meaning that I am trying to look for a way to navigate into a specific folder and then print all the files inside that specified folder.